# Strange crash reports on in-app purchase code

Tags: ios, crash, in-app-purchase, crash-reports, crashlytics

I have the following code to add in-app purchase to the application. All works perfectly on my devices. But when I add `Crashlytics` support to the application I have hundreds crash reports every day. Why? I really can't understand what is wrong on the provided code.

```
#define kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification"
#define kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification"
#define kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification"
#define gFullVersion @"%@.FullVersion"

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self loadStore];
    }
}

- (NSString*)getProductId:(NSString*)feature {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];
    NSString *bundleIdentifier = [info objectForKey: @"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    return bundleIdentifier;
}

- (void)requestProducts:(NSString*)feature {
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:[self getProductId:feature]];
    if ([feature isEqualToString:gFullVersion]) {
        if (productFullVersionRequest) {
            [productFullVersionRequest release];
            productFullVersionRequest = nil;
        }
        productFullVersionRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
        productFullVersionRequest.delegate = self;
        [productFullVersionRequest start];
        // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
    }
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    [products addObjectsFromArray:response.products];
    for (SKProduct *product in response.products) {
        if (product && [product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:gFullVersion]]) {
            // finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestCompilations
            [productFullVersionRequest release];
            productFullVersionRequest = nil;
        }
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}

// call this method once on startup
- (void)loadStore {
    // restarts any purchases if they were interrupted last time the app was open
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    // get the product description (defined in early sections)
    [self requestProducts:gFullVersion];
}

// call this before making a purchase
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases {
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}

// kick off the upgrade transaction
- (void)purchaseProduct:(NSString*)feature {
    bool ok = false;
    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:feature]]) {
            SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
            if (payment) {
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// saves a record of the transaction by storing the receipt to disk
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:gFullVersion]]) {
        // save the transaction receipt to disk
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:[self getProductId:gFullVersion]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}

// enable pro features
- (bool)provideContent:(NSString *)productId {
    if ([productId isEqualToString:[self getProductId:gFullVersion]]) {
        // ...provide content here...
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// removes the transaction from the queue and posts a notification with the transaction result
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful {
    // remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:transaction, @"transaction" , nil];
    if (wasSuccessful) {
        // send out a notification that we’ve finished the transaction
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    } else {
        // send out a notification for the failed transaction
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
}

// called when the transaction was successful
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [self recordTransaction:transaction];
    bool provided = [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

// called when a transaction has been restored and and successfully completed
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [self recordTransaction:transaction.originalTransaction];
    [self provideContent:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

// called when a transaction has failed
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
        // error!
        [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
        [self showAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"InAppPurchase", @"") alertStr:[transaction.error localizedDescription]];
    } else {
        // this is fine, the user just cancelled, so don’t notify
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}

// called when the transaction status is updated
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)processFullVersion:(id)sender {
    if ([self canMakePurchases]) {
        [self purchaseProduct:gFullVersion];
    } else {
        [self showAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"InAppPurchase", @"") alertStr:NSLocalizedString(@"CanNotMakePurchases", @"")];
    }
}

- (IBAction)restoreCompletedTransactions:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

The crash report:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xa1c57ae2
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3bf5e5d0 objc_msgSend + 15
1  StoreKit                       0x360260a7 __NotifyObserverAboutChanges + 66
2  CoreFoundation                 0x341aeacd CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
3  StoreKit                       0x36026055 -[SKPaymentQueue _notifyObserversAboutChanges:sendUpdatedDownloads:] + 128
4  StoreKit                       0x36024bc9 -[SKPaymentQueue addPayment:] + 464
5  MyApplication                  0x000a76d7 -[CalendarView purchaseProduct:] (CalendarView.m:952)
6  MyApplication                  0x000a8c17 -[CalendarView processFullVersion:] (CalendarView.m:1107)
7  MyApplication                  0x000a361b -[CalendarView clickHandler:] (CalendarView.m:458)
8  MyApplication                  0x000a55cf -[CalendarView liteVersionDisplayAlert] (CalendarView.m:671)
9  MyApplication                  0x000a5d2f -[CalendarView toggleView:] (CalendarView.m:735)
10 MyApplication                  0x000a625f -[CalendarView modeButtonPressed] (CalendarView.m:795)
11 MyApplication                  0x000c245f -[ToolbarView modePressed] (ToolbarView.m:304)
12 UIKit                          0x36162087 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 70
13 UIKit                          0x3616203b -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
14 UIKit                          0x36162015 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
15 UIKit                          0x361618cb -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 502
16 UIKit                          0x36161db9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 488
17 UIKit                          0x3608a5f9 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 524
18 UIKit                          0x360778e1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 380
19 UIKit                          0x360771ef _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6198
20 GraphicsServices               0x37d8f5f7 _PurpleEventCallback + 590
21 GraphicsServices               0x37d8f227 PurpleEventCallback + 34
22 CoreFoundation                 0x3423d3e7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
23 CoreFoundation                 0x3423d38b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 138
24 CoreFoundation                 0x3423c20f __CFRunLoopRun + 1382
25 CoreFoundation                 0x341af23d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
26 CoreFoundation                 0x341af0c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
27 GraphicsServices               0x37d8e33b GSEventRunModal + 74
28 UIKit                          0x360cb2b9 UIApplicationMain + 1120
29 MyApplication                  0x0007daff main (main.m:13)
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems an observer you added to the payment queue has been deallocated. You make calls to `SKPaymentQueue addTransactionObserver:` but you never call `SKPaymentQueue removeTransactionObserver:`.

Add a `dealloc` method to your view controller:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
}
```

Most likely your app showed a view controller which added itself as an observer. Then that view controller was dismissed (but still marked as an observer). Later you show another instance of the controller and perform some payment transaction. The payment queue then attempts to notify the old and new observers. The crash happens because the old observer has long since been deallocated.

By adding the above `dealloc` method, this issue will be resolved.

Comment: But my application creates view (observer) only once at a run. Does crash happen on the next launch of the application?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're using key value observing. I'm guessing when the app runs this section

```
- (void)purchaseProduct:(NSString*)feature {
    bool ok = false;
    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:feature]]) {
            SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
            if (payment) {
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And successfully adds a payment it goes to update an observer that isn't there, hence the bad memory access.

I would check [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

Comment: Doesn't SKPaymentQueue use KVO in order to be updated? Anyways I didn't realize it was part of Apple's Library.. I thought he had done his own implementation of addTransactionObserver:

Comment: @Apollo Aww you looked through my answers to find something to make yourself feel better? Not of KVO, but of the iOS frameworks. I also see where I was wrong. Caleb certainly provided a better solution and I understand my mistake which is why I deleted my post. I apologize for hurting your feelings, but you're a petty little man for going this far. Are you going to try googling my username next?

Comment: @Apollo We're talking about character here genius. Have you googled my name yet? Did you enjoy going around and voting down my answers?